# Server 2000 DC down after crash and restore

Tags: windows-server-2000

Problem: Server 2000 DC hard drive failed. Purchased new drive, installed server 2000 and restored everything from a backup. Everything is back up, however none of the client machines can connect to the server and view "my documents". Initially we had 3 DC, however we are down to 1 because of hardware failures so this one server is carrying all the FSMO roles.

Some of the errors:
dcgetdcname call failed
can't open the group policy (Failed to find a domain controller. There may be a policy that prevents you from selecting another domain controller.)
sometimes the active directory won't open
A Time Server could not be located.
The server holding the PDC role is down.
NIC won't save static IP settings (although the machine IP stays the same)

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

When a DC goes down, just restoring a system backup is not sufficient; you must perform an Active Directory Restore, and in your case, an authoritative restore since it is the only DC left.

Look here for details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241594

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately the only Server 2000 CD I have is SP4 and the backup was made from SP1.  Authoritative restore of a SP1 backup only works for a SP1 install....bummer.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295932.  I seriously doubt Microsoft will send me SP1 Server 2000.

Comment: You can do an unauthoritative restore and then force a refresh of all AD data; this is possible since you only have one DC.